# forge viewer: Cancel Selection Event

Tags: autodesk-forge

Trying:

```
   this.viewer.addEventListener("selection", ( args )=>{
        if( condition )
            return false;
    });
```

But it not works. 
Does it possible to prevent selection by some conditions?

Answer (score 1):

To completely cancel the selection use this:

```
this.viewer.addEventListener(
 Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, (args) => {

   if(condition) {

      this.viewer.clearSelection()
   }
})
```

To control what components are selectable, this is a harder topic, see that article: [Controlling components selection in the Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/controlling-components-selection-viewer)

Comment: this reset entire selection. what if I need prevent selection for "windows"  but allow selecting "walls"  (including  multiple selection )

Comment: I updated my previous answer, be more specific next time because it is pretty challenging to figure out what you are looking for by reading your initial question ...